# sentry use levels

Tags: django, sentry

Can I use different levels in Sentry?

my config:

```
'handlers': {
    'sentry': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
    },
    'sentry.warning': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
'loggers': {
    'my.warning': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry.warning'],
        'propagate': False,
        },
               }
```

my code:

```
    import logging
    logger_router = logging.getLogger('my.warning')
    logger_router.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logger_router.warning('my message')
```

Why all warning put in "ERROR" level?
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change from `DEBUG=False` to `DEBUG=True` in my ***settings.py***. All it's works!